# How jQuery spinner for ASP.NET postback (not Ajax)?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, postback

Using VS 2010 here.  Basically some of my linkbuttons kick off a long database query, how can I automagically display a spinner when the page is waiting for a postback?  Mind you, this isn't an ajax postback, but a normal postback after clicking a server linkbutton.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use **update panel**?

using update panel you can easily set the loading image until your call comes back.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress11" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
               <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/etls/preloader.gif" />
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                   Your content here, with the button.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I avoid the AjaxControlToolkit at all costs.

Comment: this is not AjaxControlToolkit, this is the control of ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say 2xUpdate Panel solution.  This solution is quickly implimented and effective.